# Do I earn gold with buildings?

Tags: orna

What is the point of building a shop or a blacksmith in the game? Do I earn anything other than the ability to buy/upgrade equipment in a new spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't get any "commission" from sales. It is just for enhancing player experience.